# Load CSS based on URL variable in HTML page

Tags: html, css, urlvariables

I'd like to load a stylesheet when my URL variable contains "?view=full".

Is it possible to do this in HTML (i.e. not PHP)? If so, how?

Comment: Can you use JavaScript as well, or just HTML?

Comment: Are you trying to have different CSS for a normal view and a print view?  It may be better to use [CSS media types](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html), which allow you to specify different stylesheets for screen, mobile, and print.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It’s not possible in pure HTML; you'd have to use either PHP or JavaScript. If you want to do it in JavaScript, you could put this in your `<head>` section:

```
<script>
if (window.location.search.indexOf('?view=full') === 0)
    document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="theStylesheet.css" />');
</script>
```

Comment: @alex: That actually only applies to the `<script>` tag, not any other tag.

Comment: How would this be doen with PHP?

Comment: @Shae: `<?php if (isset($_GET['view']) && $_GET['view'] === 'full') { ?><link rel="stylesheet" href="theStylesheet.css" /><?php } ?>` or something. `isset` might not be necessary, it’s been a while since I’ve written PHP.

Answer (score 4):

This will create the `link` element in your `head` element if that GET param is present.

```
if (window.location.search.search(/[?&]view=full(?:$|&)/) !== -1) {
    var link = document.createElement('link');
    link.type = 'text/css'; 
    link.rel = 'stylesheet';
    link.href = 'path/to/it.css';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
}
```

Comment: That's incorrect - you need a `<link>` element. `<style>` elements do not have an `href` attribute, nor a `rel` attribute.

Comment: @minitech Whoops, my mistake. I've fixed.

Comment: Um... "nemesis"? Anyways, yes :)